# Gardenia Buds dropping

Tags: plant-health, flowers, indoors, container-gardening

I brought a gardenia from store few weeks back.
It looked very healthy.
However, live in northern Germany and here winter days are really small and 95% of the time, it is extremely cloudy. 
The weather this year in winter is approximately -1 to 6 degrees centigrade.
I have only two windowsills but, unfortunately there are heater under them and no other place in my house gets much sunlight.
So, I had to put the plant on the windowsill near the heater.
I know it needs humidity and warm temperature.
So, for humidity, I used water pebble tray under the plant.

My plant has several new gorgeous green leaves, but all the buds are dropping before opening.
I water once a week (if I find it dry after touching the soil) and there is no way I provide proper sunlight that it needs.
I don't think I am overwatering, because, new leaves are there and they look really healthy.
Also, I didn't use any fertilizer after I brought this plant to home.

Could anyone please help me to grow flowers on this plant?

Comment: If you are taking care about humidity and watering, a likely cause is too much temperature variation between day and night, if your heaters are off at night. But they usually flower in summer and autumn, so it shouldn't really be flowering at all in January.

Comment: Yes my heaters are off at night.